# Cannot get JSONP data

Tags: javascript, vue.js, jsonp

Apologies for asking what looks like a frequently asked question but I cannot seem to be able to get the data from jsonp.

I have tried the following:

```
  window.onload = () => {
  var app = new Vue({
    el: '#app',
    data: {
      myData:[],
      t1:''
    },
    methods:{
       get(){
         this.$http.jsonp('https://sp0.baidu.com/5a1Fazu8AA54nxGko9WTAnF6hhy/su'),{
           wd:this.t1
         },{
           jsonp:'cb'
         }.then((res)=>{
           this.myData = res.data.s;
         },()=>{
           alert(res.status)
         })
       }
    }
  })
}
```

And

```
<div id="app">
<input type="text" v-model='t1' @keyup='get()'>
<ul>
  <li v-for='item in myData'>item</li>
</ul>
<p v-show='myData.length == 0'>empty...</p>
```

how do I do to solve it?

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No worries! I made [a JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/y9xjc1gx/23/) to try and figure out your specific issue. It would seem that baidu doesn't let you change the name of the jsonp callback, or at least not with any of the parameters I tried such as `cb` or `callback` or `jsonpCallback` and so on and so forth.

I then tried to tell vue-resource to manually set the actual callback name to `window.baidu.sug` but it does not [appear that vue-resource can handle](https://github.com/pagekit/vue-resource/blob/master/src/http/client/jsonp.js#L30) setting custom callback names that are nested in other objects.

In short, **you are doing *nothing* wrong** and there are two potential solutions to your problem:

1. Do you know if that baidu API allows you to set the name of the jsonp callback function via query parameter? If so, this would be quickest solution to your problem. You would then set the `jsonp` option to the name of the query parameter that baidu uses to set the query parameter name. I couldn't find it in the documentation but it seems that `cb` is not the correct query parameter name, or even if this is supported at all.
2. Submit a PR to [vue-resource](https://github.com/pagekit/vue-resource) that properly supports callback functions nested in other objects. The change would need to be made somewhere around [here](https://github.com/pagekit/vue-resource/blob/master/src/http/client/jsonp.js#L30).